# Install memcached PHP extension on openSUSE 13.2

Tags: php, php5, memcached, opensuse

Is there a standard/supported way to get the memcached extension for PHP installed on openSUSE 13.2?

On CentOS this was a case of `yum -y install php-pecl-memcached`.

But it doesn't look like the equivalent is present in the default package repos for openSUSE.

I found [this](http://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home:danci1973&package=php5-memcached) but as it's for a customer system I'd rather notleave them with anything non-standard.

Thanks in advance for any assistance,

Leon

Answer (score 1):

I ended up building this installing this via PECL, the extension having two dependencies: `cyrus-sasl-devel` which I installed from the default package repo and `libmemcached` which I built from source:

```
zypper install cyrus-sasl-devel
zypper install gcc-c++
wget https://launchpad.net/libmemcached/1.0/1.0.18/+download/libmemcached-1.0.18.tar.gz
tar -xzf libmemcached-1.0.18.tar.gz
cd libmemcached-1.0.18
./configure
make
make install
pecl install memcached
⋮
libmemcached directory [no] : /usr/local
⋮
```

Then I created file `/etc/php5/conf.d/memcached.ini` containing:

```
extension=memcached.so
```

Comment: Thanks, this also worked great on openSUSE tumbleweed. You might want to add `php5-devel` (for pecl) and `php5-pear` (pecl doesn't execute without some PEAR files) to the packages that have to be installed beforehand.